# Why Javascript fetch method putting unnecessary / in the URL

Tags: javascript, url, fetch

I am sending a GET request with parameters on the URL. The problem is that, While sending a request, The URL is modified and includes an extra "/" which is not by me. I am also using Django.

Code:

```
     let url = `ajax_vehical_types`;
          groups.map(async (x, i) => {
            if (i === 0) url += `?group[${i}]=${x}`;
            else url += `&group[${i}]=${x}`;
          });




    vehical_type = await fetch(`${window.location.origin}/${url}`)
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((data) => data);
```

Here is the result
[Image showing the console with fetch request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rz1pa.png)

Answer (score -1):

You can make usage of the [URL interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL). The advantage of this is that you don't need to bother about the construction of your URL and also about the URL encoding.

Please see the following example:

```
const groups = ["foo", "bar"];
const url = new URL(location.href);

groups.forEach((x, i) => url.searchParams.append(`group[${i}]`, x));

vehical_type = await fetch(url.toString())
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => data);
```